# php scan_it to exclude directories starting with an underscore

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code, which scans the specified directory for jpgs:

```
<?php
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("images/" . $this->item->extraFields->PropertYID->value . "");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {
if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg" &&
strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg") {

echo '<div><img src="'.$file .'" alt="" />'."</div>";
}
}
?>
```

Id simply like to exclude from this scan any folders which name start with an underscore (_).

To clarify if the directory structure was the following:

```
/images/interior/

/images/exterior/

/images/_room1/

/images/room2/

/images/room3/
```

All directories except _room1 would be included.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check if the code i gave is working or not ?

Comment: @Amit Ray Sorry ive only just had a chance to check, im afraid its not working, its still finding all images regardless of the _ at the beginning of the folder name, many thanks for your help though Amit!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for '_' in the folder name

```
$directory = "images/' . $this->item->extraFields->PropertYID->value '";
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach($files as $name => $file){
        if(is_dir($file)){ //Edited
             $pos = strpos($file, '_');
        }
         if($pos === false){
            if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg" &&
            strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg") {

            echo '<div><img src="'.$file .'" alt="" />'."</div>";
            }
          }
    }
```

If you want to remove directory with only the first character as '_' and its ok if its in middle then you can do this

```
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $name => $file){
    if(is_dir($file)){
         $pos = strpos($file, '_');
    }
     if(($pos === false) || $pos>0){
        if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg" &&
        strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg") {

        echo '<div><img src="'.$file .'" alt="" />'."</div>";
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: So sorry in the delay in my reply! But im afraid its not working, many thanks for your help though!!!

Comment: Thats very strange, I just checked again also, and renamed all folders with an _ but the script still finds all images. (An irrelevant note but proves to me I have everything setup correctly: I have other php code also in this page which calls images but as I renamed the folders they are not being found.) Thanks again for your help Amit!

Comment: I dont suppose you have any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong? Its definetly not working for me:( Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @jimmywiddle there was a minor syntax error. I have corrected it can you check now. I used double quotes instead of single quotes while answering.